# rewriting the set $\{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2{e^{-t}} + \alpha_3{e^{-2t}} \leq 1.1 \text{ for } t \geq 1 \}$

Tags: inequality, elementary-set-theory, exponential-function

According to the accepted answer of this question:

[Proof that set is not a polyhedron.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825154/proof-that-set-is-not-a-polyhedron/3829337#3829337)

the following sets are equal:

- $\{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2{e^{-t}} + \alpha_3{e^{-2t}}  \leq 1.1 \text{ for some }  t \geq 1 \}$
- $\{ \alpha \in R^3 \mid (1,t,t^2)^T \alpha\le {11 \over 10}, \text{ for some } t \in (0,1] \}$

this is presented as trivial in the answer, and certainly it is, but I would like some intuition or explanation why this is the case.

Comment: Do you really mean $\{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2^{e^{-t}} + \alpha_3^{e^{-2t}}  \leq 1.1 \text{ for }  t \geq 1 \}$, or just $\{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2{e^{-t}} + \alpha_3{e^{-2t}}  \leq 1.1 \text{ for }  t \geq 1 \}$ ?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Thanks for the comment. I corrected the question.

Comment: Ok, then just make the substitution $u=e^{-t}$. You get that $$\{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2{e^{-t}} + \alpha_3{e^{-2t}}  \leq 1.1 \text{ for }  t \geq 1 \} = \{\alpha \in R^3 \mid \alpha_1 + \alpha_2u + \alpha_3u^2  \leq 1.1 \text{ for }  u \in (0,e^{-1}] \}$$
which is (nearly) what you want.

Comment: @Vince - I made some changes to your question to clarify the definitions of the sets (the question of whether "for" meant "for all" or "for some" was brought up in that thread, and the author chose "for some"). And "equivalent" is a much looser term than "equal", with many different definitions based on the context. Copperhat said they were the same set. I.e., that they are equal.

Comment: @copperhat - would you mind looking into this question about an old answer of yours? It seems to me that in your converted form for the set, you were taking the original set as having $t \ge 0$, not $t \ge 1$ as is actually given. But as your set notation was abbreviated, I am not sure I am interpreting it correctly.